# Limit of $1 - \cos(x)$ as $x$ tends to zero.

Tags: calculus, limits

Does the limit of $1 - \cos(x)$ as $x$ tends to zero exist? If yes, what is it? Can it be that the limit of 
$$
\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}
$$ 
as $x$ tends to zero is $1$?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: Limit of (1-cosx)/x as x tends to zero is 1, so one would expect limit of 1-cosx as x tends to 0 to be x.

Comment: @SoumilAggarwal with the limit the first check is to verify if $f(x)$ is continuos in $x_0$ in these case you simply have that $f(x)\to f(x_0)$. To check continuity fo elementary functions it is sufficient verify the ordinary condition for the existence of $f(x)$.

Comment: @SoumilAggarwal Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without resorting to continuity:**

$$1-\cos x=2\sin^2\dfrac x2.$$

Then taking the limit of $\sin x/x$ for granted,

$$\lim_{x\to0}2\sin^2\frac x2=2\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2}\dfrac x2\right)^2=2\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac x2\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering, as limit of (1-cosx)/x as x tends to zero is one, why can't limit of (1-cosx) as x tends to zero be x?

Comment: @SoumilAggarwal: yes, this is true. But the property you mention is a little "stronger" than that of $\sin x/x$ and is better known in the form of $(1-\cos )/x^2=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a continuos function in $0$ thus

$$1-\cos(x)\to 1-\cos(0)=0$$

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Can the limit be $x$?

Comment: @Soumil But $x \to 0,$ so after limit taken no more $x.$

Comment: @SoumilAggarwal the funcion exist in x=0, is continuous in x=0 and takes the value 0, thus the limit is $f(0)=0$. Moreover x can't never appear in the result since it is tending to some value.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos{(x)}\;is \;a \;{\color{red} {Continuous \;function}}$, So:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}[1-\cos{(x)]}=1-\cos{(0)}=0$$

Comment: Question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the l'Hospital rule to get:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{1} = 0.
$$